# A jQuery Class Paradox

Tags: jquery, class, function

I can't understand this.

When I want to **remove** class `B` from a `div` and **add** class `D` into it,

It works.

But class `D`'s  function can't be triggered.

```
$('.B').click(function() { 
        $('.A').animate({
           "left": "+=10%"
        },{
           duration:1000,
           complete: function(){
              $("#C").addClass("D").removeClass("B");
              } 
           }); 
});  



 $(".D").click(function() { 
        $(".A").animate({
            "top":"+=40%"
        },{
            duration:2000,
            complete:function(){
                 $("#C").addClass("B").removeClass("D");
             }
          });
}); ​
```

---

I've tried putting  class `D`'s  function into  class `B`'s  function like this:

```
$('.B').click(function() { 
        $('.A').animate({
           "left": "+=10%"
        },{
           duration:1000,
           complete: function(){
              $("#C").addClass("D").removeClass("B");
              $(".D").click(function() { 
                   $(".A").animate({
                       "top":"+=40%"
                   },{
                       duration:2000,
                       complete:function(){
                           $("#C").addClass("B").removeClass("D");
                       }
                   });
               }); ​
              } 
           }); 
});
```

and both functions work for the **first time** and after that they behavior in a bizarre way.

I would appreciate if someone can explain to me why and provide me with a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `$.click`,  you bind only to the elements that match the select *at that time*. If you want to match all future elements as well, use `$.on` instead:

```
$("body").on("click", ".D", function(){
  /* Class D Stuff */
});
```

This will react whether the clicked element had `class="D"` to begin with, or if it acquired it later on through something like `$(this).addClass("D")`.

The `"body"` part ideally should be a container much closer to your clicked elements. For instance, if  you had the following:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <a href="#" class="B">Foo</a>
    <a href="#" class="D">Bar</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

You should use `#container` instead of `body` in the jQuery function.